# Js-фреймворк

Tags: javascript

Нужен простейший js-фреймворк. Главное чтобы там были приличные роутеры, шаблонизатор и модели; особенных примочек не нужно. Посоветуйте

Answer (score 3):

Естественно [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)! Есть русифицированная документация: [Backbone.js по-русски](http://backbonejs.ru/).

Comment: Под понятие простой он не совсем подходит:)

Comment: это так кажется, на самом деле он может использовать jQuery и Underscore.js, а может и не использовать, всё, что он предоставляет это действительно мощные роуты+историю и событийную модель зависимостей моделей и представлений, ну и ещё RESTful API для backend`а

-------------
хотя возможно вы найдёте что-то именно для себя здесь: [jswiki](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki)

Answer (score 1):

[Spine.js](http://spinejs.com/)

Comment: у меня почему-то к CoffeScript смешанные чувства, с одной стороны в нём много удобного даже с точки зрения синтаксиса языка, но с другой - что-то в нём рубистское, что меня отталкивает